# FFmpeg: Interpolation for Fade-In

Tags: ffmpeg, interpolation, fade, envelope

I’m currently using the following to fade-in a short film.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v fade=in:0:360 -c:v libx264 -preset:v slower -crf:v 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

---

Everything works as expected; however, the interpolation of the fade is not what I’m after (seems to be linear). I’d like to play around with exponential, cubic, sinusoidal, etc.

Is there any way to achieve this with FFmpeg? The visual material I’m working with is pure white and pure black, and the fade-in as it stands is too harsh; I can see the material appear almost as soon as the fade starts as a result of the (apparently) linear progression. I’d like it to be more organic.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not directly. One method is to perform a **white to black** fade in a video editor and export that. Keep the duration of this clip long. Within ffmpeg, that clip can be used as an alpha matte for a black canvas that can be overlaid over your main video. Its duration can be shortened as required. ...  The other method is speculation on my part but if possible, can be entirely done in ffmpeg. Generate a synthetic audio stream. Apply audio fade out filter to it. This has various interpolations available. Convert it to a video stream. Use this as alpha for a blank cavas as in first method.

Comment: Very helpful suggestions: many thanks.